# Find the terms of a geometric progression given two partial sums.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, geometric-progressions

> Given an **increasing** geometric progression such that:
> $$a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=93\qquad\text{ and }\qquad a_2+a_4=30,$$
> find $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, $a_4$, $a_5$ **without using the sum formula**.

What I did: Let $q$ denote the common ratio of the geometric progression, so that
$$a_1q+a_1q^3=30\qquad\text{ and }\qquad a_1+a_1q+a_1q^2+a_1q^3+a_1q^4=93.$$

Dividing the two equations yields
$$\frac{1+q+q^2+q^3+q^4}{q+q^3}=\frac{93}{30},$$

but I don't know how to solve this equation.

**Edit:** I edited the question so that $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=93$ and **NOT**
$a_1+a_2+a_3=93$.

Comment: That equation can be written $31q^3 - 10q^2 + 21q - 10 = 0$, which has no solutions with $q > 1$.  So there is no such progression.

Comment: Are you sure it's an increasing progression? When I solve it, I find a decreasing geometric progression.

Comment: sorry i edited my question. it was $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5=93$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

\begin{align}
a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5&=93\\
a_1+(a_2+a_4)(1+q)&=93\\
a_1+30(1+q)&=93\\
a_1&=63-30q
\end{align}

Then:

\begin{align}
a_2+a_4&=30\\
a_1q(1+q^2)&=30\\
(63-30q)q(1+q^2)&=30\\
(21-10q)q(1+q^2)&=10\\
\iff 10q^4-21q^3+10q^2-21q+10&=0
\end{align}

Now try with the Rational Root Theorem.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot it really helped!

Comment: Another way to finish, without appealing to the Rational Root Theorem, is to note that the last polynomial is *palindromic*. In fact the value of $q$ can be found using only the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a thorough explanation of my comment on Mario G's answer; I could not fit a clear explanation into the comments, and I felt like writing something up. His answer is a quick and clean solution, which I like very much. This answer uses the simpler quadratic formula in stead of the rational root theorem. All credit for the middle part of my answer (from equations $(1)$ to $(3)$) goes to Mario G, as it is essentialy the same argument.

---

Suppose $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ is such a geometric progression. It is clear that $a_1\neq0$ as otherwise all terms in the progression equal $0$, in which case their sum cannot equal $93$. Let $a:=a_1$ the base factor and $q:=\tfrac{a_2}{a_1}$ the common ratio of the sequence, and note that $q>0$  because the progression is increasing. Moreover, if $q<1$ then $a_1<0$ for the same reason, but then all terms in the progression are negative, in which case their sum again cannot equal $93$. Therefore $q>1$.

We can rewrite the given equations as
\begin{eqnarray}
a+aq+aq^2+aq^3+aq^4&=&\ 93,\tag{1}\\
aq+aq^3&=&\ 30.\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}
We can take out the left hand side of $(2)$ from the left hand side of $(1)$ as follows:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a+aq+aq^2+aq^3+aq^4
&=&\ a+(aq+aq^3)+(aq^2+aq^4)\\
&=&\ a+(aq+aq^3)+q(aq+aq^3)\\
&=&\ a+(aq+aq^3)(1+q).
\end{eqnarray*}
Then plugging in the numbers from $(1)$ and $(2)$ shows us that $93=a+30(1+q)$, or equivalently 
$$a=93-30(1+q)=63-30q.$$
Substituting this back into equation $(2)$ yields
$$30=(63-30q)q+(63-30q)q^3=63q-30q^2+63q^3-30q^4,$$
and now rearranging the terms and dividing by $3$ we see that $q$ satisfies the quartic equation
$$10q^4-21q^3+10q^2-21q+10=0.\tag{3}$$
[Solving a quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) is generally [not fun](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Quartic_Formula.svg), but in this case it is${}^☺$ because it's a [palindromic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Palindromic_and_antipalindromic_polynomials)! This allows us to use a neat trick; we can divide equation $(3)$ by $q^2$ (because we already saw $q>0$) to get a *quadratic* equation in terms of $q+q^{-1}$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
q^{-2}(10q^4-21q^3+10q^2-21q+10)
&=&10q^2-21q+10-21q^{-1}+10q^{-2}\\
&=&10(q^2+q^{-2})-21(q+q^{-1})+10\\
&=&10(q+q^{-1})^2-21(q+q^{-1})-10.
\end{eqnarray*}
Be careful to note what happens with the squares in the last step! Now we see that $q+q^{-1}$ is a root of the quadratic polynomial $10x^2-21x-10$ with discriminant $29^2$, so by the quadratic formula
$$q+q^{-1}=\frac{21}{20}\pm\frac{1}{20}\cdot29,$$
where $q+q^{-1}>0$ because $q>0$, so we must have the '$+$'-sign with $q+q^{-1}=\tfrac{21}{20}+\tfrac{29}{20}=\tfrac52$. Multiplying through by $q$ and rearranging terms shows that $q$ is a root of the quadratic equation
$$x^2-\tfrac52x+1=0,$$
with discriminant $\left(\tfrac{3}{2}\right)^2$, so by the quadratic formula
$q=\tfrac54\pm\tfrac12\cdot\tfrac32$. Because $q>1$ we get 
$$q=\tfrac54+\tfrac12\cdot\tfrac32=2\qquad\text{ and }\qquad a=63-30q=3,$$
so the *unique* such geometric progression is
$$(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)=(3,6,12,24,48).$$

---

☺: This may depend on your definition of fun.

Comment: thank you! i thought about it when i saw the last equation in Mario G's answer:) symmetry is fun+